# Postgres - Splitting a row into multiple rows based on two datetime fields to get logged minutes each hour

Tags: postgresql

### What I want to Achieve.

I have a table called `calls` which has columns `started_at:datetime`, `end_at:datetime`, `handler:string`.

| id | started_at | end_at | handler | agent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-05T02:00:00Z | 2021-04-05T03:30:00Z | fg456fghj | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-04-05T03:40:00Z | 2021-04-05T04:30:00Z | cvbnmfghh | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-04-05T04:40:00Z | 2021-04-05T05:00:00Z | wertyuuuu | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-04-06T01:40:00Z | 2021-04-05T02:00:00Z | 34sdfertt | 1 |

I want a new table that looks like this

| id | hour | minutes_logged |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02 of 2021-04-05 | 60 |
| 2 | 03 of 2021-04-05 | 50 |
| 3 | 04 of 2021-04-05 | 50 |
| 4 | 01 of 2021-04-06 | 20 |

**Note**:
`minutes_logged` cannot exceed 60 minutes as an hour only has 60 minutes.

---

### My Findings

For the `hour` column I could write is

```sql
concat(extract(hour from calls.started_at), ' of ', calls.started_at::date) as hour
```

But I could not write for `minutes_logged` properly.

### Main problem

I could not write a query to break the time range into multiple rows. Please help. I appreciate your effort. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can approach this by first generating a calendar table covering all minutes on all dates in your data set.  Then, inner join to your data table and aggregate by the hour (and day) to generate the counts:

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '2021-04-05'::date AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-04-06'::date
),
minutes AS (
    SELECT (n || ' minute')::INTERVAL AS min
    FROM generate_series(0, 1439) n
)

SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('hour', d.dt + m.min),
    COUNT(*) AS minutes_logged
FROM dates d
CROSS JOIN minutes m
INNER JOIN yourTable t
   ON d.dt + m.min >= t.started_at AND d.dt + m.min < t.end_at
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('hour', d.dt + m.min)
ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('hour', d.dt + m.min);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

---

**Note:** To support wide range of start and end dates following can be implemented

```sql
    with dates AS (
        select * from generate_series(timestamp '2019-12-08'::date, '2021-04-09'::date, '1 day') as dt
    ),
```

Comment: Tim, this solution seems to be inefficient with a large database. Because there are millions of records in my production table. Could you please also post a lesser time-consuming solution?

Comment: No, I can't do that, because I know of no other solution than what I posted above.  You might be able to try indexing your table: `CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (started_at, end_at)` ... this might at least speed up the join between the calendar table and your data table.